# UnderscoreJS : Getting only top 5 using the _.each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have array of object and i want to access the properties of this object using _.each method
which is working fine

```
var x = [{id:1, name:"xyz"},{id:2, name:"pqr"},...and so on]
```

and i am accessing using _.each method

```
_.each(x ,function(param){console.log("id:" + param.Id +" and name:"+ param.name);});
```

I want to display only the top 5 of x
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_.first()` to take the first 5 before using `_.each()`...

```
_.each(_.first(x, 5) ,function(param){console.log("id:" + param.Id +" and name:"+ param.name);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **slice**

```
_.each(x.slice(0,5) ,function(param){
    console.log("id:" + param.Id +" and name:"+ param.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't break _.each. The right way to do this using underscore is _.find (http://underscorejs.org/#find). Or use Array.prototype.every (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) but you have to look for browser compatibility. Both break by returning false.